# SQL Query for players average hot streak duration

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have a table with three columns and the following data:

```
* gamedate,playername,pointsScored
* 20180101,George,34
* 20180102,George,37
* 20180103,George,38
* 20180104,George,3
* 20180105,George,35
* 20180106,George,37
* 20180107,George,31
* 20180108,George,31
* 20180109,George,32
* 20180110,George,7
```

I'm looking for a `sql query` that tells me on average how many games in a row can this player maintain a score of 30+.  I know it would have to be some sort of `group by` function but I'm kind of stuck on how to formulate this query.  This is an `Oracle table` if that makes any difference.

Some additional date for testing:

```
with
inputs(gamedate,playername,pointsscored) as (
select to_date('20180912','yyyymmdd'), 'George',52 from dual union all
select to_date('20180907','yyyymmdd'), 'George',47 from dual union all
select to_date('20180829','yyyymmdd'), 'George',9 from dual union all
select to_date('20180823','yyyymmdd'), 'George',55 from dual union all
select to_date('20180818','yyyymmdd'), 'George',49 from dual union all
select to_date('20180811','yyyymmdd'), 'George',58 from dual union all
select to_date('20180805','yyyymmdd'), 'George',31 from dual union all
select to_date('20180730','yyyymmdd'), 'George',40 from dual union all
select to_date('20180720','yyyymmdd'), 'George',44 from dual union all
select to_date('20180712','yyyymmdd'), 'George',45 from dual union all
select to_date('20180707','yyyymmdd'), 'George',29 from dual union all
select to_date('20180701','yyyymmdd'), 'George',-5 from dual union all
select to_date('20180626','yyyymmdd'), 'George',46 from dual union all
select to_date('20180620','yyyymmdd'), 'George',22 from dual union all
select to_date('20180614','yyyymmdd'), 'George',49 from dual union all
select to_date('20180609','yyyymmdd'), 'George',40 from dual union all
select to_date('20180602','yyyymmdd'), 'George',40 from dual
)
```

Comment: Trying to understand the problem... in your sample, are we looking at two streaks, one of three games and the other of five games, and the average you are looking for is 4? No matter how many games with less than 30 points scored are between the steaks, or before the first one or after the last one?

Comment: yes mathguy that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle 12.1 or higher, the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause can do quick work of such assignments:

```
with
  inputs(gamedate,playername,pointsscored) as (
    select to_date('20180101','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 34 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180102','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 37 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180103','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 38 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180104','yyyymmdd'), 'George',  3 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180105','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 35 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180106','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 37 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180107','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 31 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180108','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 31 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180109','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 32 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180109','yyyymmdd'), 'George',  7 from dual
  )
select playername, avg(cnt) as average_streak
from   inputs
match_recognize(
  partition by playername
  order by     gamedate
  measures     count(*) as cnt
  one row per match
  pattern ( a+ )
  define a as pointsscored >= 30
)
group by playername
;

PLAYER AVERAGE_STREAK
------ --------------
George              4
```

Explanation:

`MATCH_RECOGNIZE` partitions the input rows by player, and orders them within each partition by game date. A "match" is an occurrence of one or more consecutive rows (the `a+` in the `PATTERN` sub-clause) with 30 or more points scored (see the `DEFINE` subclause). `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` returns one row for each match it finds, and specifically it returns the player name and the count of rows in the match (which is the length of the streak, in number of consecutive rows, or games). The outer query groups by player and takes the average streak length.

Comment: are you aware that you doubled the answer friend :)

Comment: mathguy Thanks you so much!!  This is exactly what I needed.  And the query is so simple!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - I assume you didn't really mean I "doubled" the answer (meaning, posted the same answer twice). Rather, I posted two answers to the same question. Yes, I am aware - I do that sometimes, when I offer two completely different and unrelated answers to the same question (often, one answer may be better, but will only work in the most recent versions of Oracle). As far as I know, this is OK, as it should be.

Comment: Yes, I meant the second case "two answers to the same question".

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. It uses the Tabibitosan (or "fixed differences") method to recognize streaks - that's the difference of two ROW_NUMBER calls in the inner query. The rest is grouping and taking aggregate functions.

The WITH clause is to simulate the data; it is not part of the solution, it should be removed before testing the solution on actual data. (Use your actual table name instead of INPUTS in the inner query.)

```
with
  inputs(gamedate,playername,pointsscored) as (
    select to_date('20180101','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 34 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180102','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 37 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180103','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 38 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180104','yyyymmdd'), 'George',  3 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180105','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 35 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180106','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 37 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180107','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 31 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180108','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 31 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180109','yyyymmdd'), 'George', 32 from dual union all
    select to_date('20180109','yyyymmdd'), 'George',  7 from dual
  )
select   playername, avg(ct) as average_streak
from     (
           select playername, count(*) as ct
           from   (
                    select playername, pointsscored,
                           row_number() over (partition by playername 
                                                order by gamedate)
                           - row_number() over (partition by playername,
                                                 case when pointsscored >= 30 
                                                      then 0 end
                                                 order by gamedate) as grp
                    from   inputs
                  )
           group by playername, grp
           having   min(pointsscored) >= 30
         )
group by playername
order by playername
;
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
PLAYER AVERAGE_STREAK
------ --------------
George              4
```

Comment: mathguy I was able to run this query but it wasn't given me the answer I was expecting for some data sets.  I updated my question with the data I was using to test this.

Comment: @themosquito - I just ran this query with the new data. I get the result 3.25, which is correct: there are four streaks, of lengths 2, 7, 1 and 3. 13/4 = 3.25, or do you consider a "streak" of length 1 (a single game with more than 30 points, between two games with less than 30 points) as "not a streak"? In both solutions, I consider that as a streak of length 1. If a single 30+ point game is not a streak, then both queries must be modified, and both can be modified very easily for this different definition. (Also, did George really score negative five points in one game?)

Comment: That's so weird it get a result of 2 running the query with the same exact data I pasted  at the end of my question.  But yes you're right the answer should be 3.25.  And yes George actually did score -5 in one game.  Hence the curiosity on my part on how a really good player who mostly scores over 40 points seemingly has a bad game every 3rd or 4th game.  And the bad games don't line up with harder opponents.  So I wanted to run some analysis on the data to see on average how many good games can him and other players in his positions can maintain a win streak before they have a bad game. :)

Comment: @themosquito - how can a player, ANY player, score a NEGATIVE number of points? Do you mean he scored 5 points? What does it even mean to score -5 points? In soccer perhaps you would count own goals as negative goals; what would that mean in basketball?